# mongodb failover Demonstration! Help needed

Tags: mongodb

Here is a newbie trying to play around Mongodb. I am trying to demonstrate scaling in my class, meaning, I need to show that I have 2 instances of mongoDB up and running and I need to replicate them, set one as master and the other as secondary.

Can any of you suggest me a simple way to demonstrate that if primary/master fails the slave/secondary comes up as the master?

Please keep it as simple as possible as I am teaching to a fairly beginners of MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/) are *not* master/slave. In order to achieve automatic failover you need to have a majority of nodes in the replica set able to elect a new primary. The minimum number of nodes in your replica set should be 3, which can either be 3 data-bearing nodes or 2 data-bearing nodes and an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/), which is a node that votes in elections.

A demo using replication alone is more about failover and redundancy than scaling (better demo'd with sharding).

If you want a very simple (and **non-production**) way to stand up a replica set or sharded cluster in a development environment, I would suggest using the `mlaunch` script which is part of [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch).

For example, to create a 3-node replica set with an arbiter:

```
mlaunch --replicaset --nodes 2 --arbiter
```

To create a sharded cluster with 3 shards backed by a replica set (plus `mongos` and config server):

```
mlaunch --replicaset --sharded 3
```

As mentioned in the other comments here, the free [MMS Monitoring](http://mms.mongodb.com/) service is a good way to visualise activity in your MongoDB deployment, and you can use `db.shutdownServer()` to shutdown specific nodes to see the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set up the [MongoDB monitoring service](https://mms.mongodb.com/).  Stop the MongoD process on one and watch the other take over.  But, use replica sets rather than master/secondary as they are [the recommended approach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/replica-sets/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is pretty easy

1. Set up a replica set with 2 "normal" `mongod`s and an arbiter
2. Connect to both of the normal `mongod`s using `mongo`
3. Show the output of `rs.status()`. (Note the `self`field)
4. Shut down the current primary
5. Show the output of `rs.status()` again and again, until the former secondary is elected primary

Another option would be to write a simple java app which utilizes the driver, put it in an infinite loop which writes one entry every second and puts out the number of objects in the database. Catch exceptions and write out that a problem occurred. Start the sharded cluster, then start your application. Shut down the primary while the program is running. during the elections, there may be exceptions be thrown. As soon as the former secondary is elected primary, the document count should start to rise again.

Comment: This is what I see in MMS. is this right?LAST PING Type   Repl Set  
WIN-RVG4NTU8372:27001  PRIMARY   replication  
WIN-RVG4NTU8372:27002 Secondary   replication  
WIN-RVG4NTU8372:27003 Secondary   replication

Comment: How do i Shutdown the primary alone? I used { shutdown: 1, force: true } but it never worked

Comment: Either you simply kill the process with SIGTERM, or you connect to the primary and do a `use admin; db.shutdownServer()